# PHP Multidimensional Array or better option?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a code that takes posted data from form A and then find the prices of goods and display them. Now i need to do more with the following data in the body of the 2nd form:
Item name
Item Qty
Item Price

The code is here:

```
<?php
echo "<div style='width:30%; height:auto; border: 2px solid;'>";
    echo "<h1>The Items Are...</h1><br>";
    //array that will hold the sum of each item cost
    $totalAmountArray = array();

    foreach ($_POST['basket'] as $name => $value) 
    {
        //indexer for totalAmountArray
        $i=0;
        if($value > 0){
                //echo $name . ": " . $value . "<br>";

            $itemPrice;
            //reassign 
            $itemName = $name;

            $itemQty = $value;
            //sql connection..
            mysql_connect();
            mysql_select_db("xxxxxx");
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pricing WHERE item = '".$name."'");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $itemPrice = $row['price'];
                /*DEBUGGING*/
                echo "Item Name: <b>".$itemName . " </b>@ ";
                echo "<b>".$itemPrice ." </b>X ".$itemQty."<br>";
            }//end of while loop

            //multiply to get total for this item - store in temp
            $temp = $itemQty * $itemPrice;
            //store temp at index i in totalAmountArray
            array_push($totalAmountArray, $temp);
            unset($result);
            unset($itemPrice);
            unset($itemQty);
            unset($temp);
        }//end of if-statement
    }//end of foreach
    echo "<h1>Total Amount:<br></h1> ";
    //print_r($totalAmountArray);
    $sum;
    foreach($totalAmountArray as $perItemPrice){
        $sum += $perItemPrice;
    }
    echo "<b>SR. ".$sum."</b>";
echo "</div>";
?>
```

I am thinking of storing all the details returned from above foreach's into multidimensional array to have something like this:

```
[0] => itemName => itemQty => itemPrice <br>
[1] => itemName => itemQty => itemPrice <br>
[2] => itemName => itemQty => itemPrice <br>
[3] => itemName => itemQty => itemPrice <br>
.....
```

would this be the best way? and how can it be done? I am really unfamiliar with multidimensional arrays in practice (only in theory).

Thanks a lot for the help and advice,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong but since you want an advise I just do not see the point on why would you use a two dimensional array in this situation (although I may misunderstood your question and may wrong but I think the best way to solve your problem is to create a class Item in that class has a variables itemName itemQty itemPrice and then store information about every object item in to an array

Comment: so create an object and store those values in class variables...I can do that I guess. I will try coding it now...shouldn't take long to know if it fails or not..so stay tuned :) Thanks mate

Comment: I did that I believe it is working now..now I can organize the display as I want at least I think

Answer (score 1):

Hold an array of an array. Making multi dimensional arrays can get a little confusing. For each item, it holds an array of all its data. Another way is to make an object (class), say "items" which holds each piece of data from the form. Each form submission object is then put into an array for sorting and retrieval.

So it would be

```
[sudo PHP]
class foo
{
     int formID
     string submitterName
     string bar
}

foo->formID = $row['id']

myArray[lastPosition + 1] = foo

for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++)
{
    echo foo[i]->formID 
}
```

I haven't touched PHP in years, sorry about the wierd half-PHP looking code, just thought I might deliver an answer quickly!

Comment: :P I was wondering about the looks of the code. it is a one submit with many values coming in. Each item submitted will have two other attributes (price and quantity). So I doubt the above helps when it comes to that really...but thanks for trying

Comment: You can have classes within classes. So you can have an object for each type of data which holds its subset of data. Keep breaking it down further and further. Trust me, this is how data is organized in advanced applications. Its the easiest to modify if something changes. You want to try to avoid strict structures which are limited by their own nature.